# Deriving the correct expression for the action of the scalar field at the time of inflation

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, cosmological-inflation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In its matrix form, the FRW metric is $$g^{\rm FRW}_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -\frac{a^2}{1-kr^2} & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & -a^2r^2 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & -a^2r^2\sin^2\theta\end{pmatrix}.$$ It's determinant is therefore, $$\det g=g=-\frac{a^6r^4\sin^2\theta}{1-kr^2}\Rightarrow \sqrt{-g}\neq a^3.$$

Assuming homogeneity $\nabla\phi=0$, the action of scalar field during inflation is $$S=\int d^4x\sqrt{-g}\left(\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\phi\partial_\nu\phi-V(\phi)\right)=\int d^4x\sqrt{-g}\left(\frac{1}{2}\dot\phi^2-V(\phi)\right).$$ But since $\sqrt{-g}\neq a^3$ my expression does not match with D. Tong's expression ([1.81](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/cosmo/cosmo.pdf), NB: PDF to a preprint of Tong's text). How is this obtained starting from the Lagrangian above? Please help me spot my mistake.

The question remains after the existing answer by Kyle Kanos. Why does my result not agree with Tong's result even for $k=0$ if I choose to use spherical coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Tong says he is using $k=0$, so one can easily use
$$
\mathrm d\Sigma^2=\mathrm dx^2+\mathrm dy^2+\mathrm dz^2$$
instead of using radial coordinates. And hence your FLRW metric is of the form,
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\text{diag}(1,\,-a^2,\,-a^2,\,-a^2).$$
This clearly gives the desired form of
$$g=-a^6\Rightarrow \sqrt{-g}=a^3$$

Comment: I did not get. What about $r^4\sin^2\theta$?

Comment: You're using Cartesian coordinates, so there is no $r$ values...

Comment: What if one chooses spherical coordinates? $d^4x$ can also stand for $dt (r^2\sin\theta)drd\theta d\phi$

Comment: Then you clearly get those pesky sine functions and $r$ terms appearing that make your life more difficult (because you'd have to cancel them out with the gradient operators, I imagine). Or you could make life super easy and just user Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: The way you did this applies only to flat geometry ($k=0$), which is not the general case. Am I correct?

Comment: This is the way Tong does it, as stated in his last paragraph on page 71.

Comment: But yes, the argument really only works for $k=0$, which is also something Tong notes in that aforementioned paragraph.

Comment: Is it okay to work with $k=0$ at the time of inflation? One of the goal of inflation is to explain the flatness of the universe.

Comment: I'm not a cosmologist by any means, but I suspect that a $k=0$ would not be reasonable for inflationary period. You may want to ask someone else this question, though.